# What does `ls --author` mean?

Tags: command-line, coreutils

What exactly means

```
ls --author
```

It really returns writer of a file or owner? How to set author for a file? I have to implement this part (`ls --author`), so need to know what exactly it is.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Ubuntu manual page for "ls" neither explains what the "author" is and it also does not  mention that the option only applies to long format.
From a [GNU/Hurd](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/What-information-is-listed.html) man page:

--author  List each file's author when producing long format directory
listings. In GNU/Hurd, file authors can differ from their owners, but
in other operating systems the two are the same.

Example:

```
ls -l --author
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 rinzwind rinzwind rinzwind 20 2011-06-18 19:33 Desktop
```

will shows 3 names instead of 2 (owner, group, author).

I found some good information on this on an [old mail archive for gnu](http://www.mail-archive.com/help-hurd@gnu.org/msg02297.html) from 2002 but in Ubuntu it is the same as the user name.

If you need to set 'author' the idea is you create a man page for your function and add an author tag in the man page. Unless you use something other than Ubuntu and actually can set this.

Answer (score 5):

On Ubuntu (and apparently any GNU/Linux) "author" is the same as owner.

See the info page (not the manpage) for coreutils/ls (`info ls`), or http://lists.centos.org/pipermail/centos/2006-March/019813.html.

Digression follows.

> I have to implement this part(ls --author)

For what? Sounds like homework. I don't have a problem helping someone with homework, but I was a little bummed to find the answer after about 30 seconds of searching the web.

Maybe a "homework" tag on askubuntu.com would be useful, just for full disclosure.